# How do I read from a version resource in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, resources, version

I have a version resource in my resources in a C++ project which contains version number, copyright and build details.  Is there an easy way to access this at run-time to populate my *help/about* dialog as I am currently maintaining seperate const values of this information.  Ideally, the solution should work for Windows/CE mobile and earlier versions of Visual C++ (6.0 upwards).

Comment: You should note that using `_get_pgmptr()` or `_get_wpgmptr()` is better than `GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFilename, MAX_PATH)`; saves you from unnecessary allocation and clarify your intention.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is an edited version of my original answer.

```
bool GetProductAndVersion(CStringA & strProductName, CStringA & strProductVersion)
{
    // get the filename of the executable containing the version resource
    TCHAR szFilename[MAX_PATH + 1] = {0};
    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFilename, MAX_PATH) == 0)
    {
        TRACE("GetModuleFileName failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    // allocate a block of memory for the version info
    DWORD dummy;
    DWORD dwSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(szFilename, &dummy);
    if (dwSize == 0)
    {
        TRACE("GetFileVersionInfoSize failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    std::vector<BYTE> data(dwSize);

    // load the version info
    if (!GetFileVersionInfo(szFilename, NULL, dwSize, &data[0]))
    {
        TRACE("GetFileVersionInfo failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    // get the name and version strings
    LPVOID pvProductName = NULL;
    unsigned int iProductNameLen = 0;
    LPVOID pvProductVersion = NULL;
    unsigned int iProductVersionLen = 0;

    // replace "040904e4" with the language ID of your resources
    if (!VerQueryValue(&data[0], _T("\\StringFileInfo\\040904e4\\ProductName"), &pvProductName, &iProductNameLen) ||
        !VerQueryValue(&data[0], _T("\\StringFileInfo\\040904e4\\ProductVersion"), &pvProductVersion, &iProductVersionLen))
    {
        TRACE("Can't obtain ProductName and ProductVersion from resources\n");
        return false;
    }

    strProductName.SetString((LPCSTR)pvProductName, iProductNameLen);
    strProductVersion.SetString((LPCSTR)pvProductVersion, iProductVersionLen);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where do you find the language ID?

Comment: @JeffB I'd start at the MSDN page [Language Identifier Constants and Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Both your last two lines gives me a `'void ATL::CSimpleStringT<char,false>::SetString(const char *,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'const char *'.`. I've `#include <atlstr.h>`

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni use `LPCSTR` instead, sorry.

Comment: The example in the [`VerQueryValue` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647464(v=vs.85).aspx) uses `VerQueryValue` with `lpSubBlock = _T("\\VarFileInfo\\Translation")` to get the translation information.

Comment: Complete language identifier table can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/aa381049(v=vs.85).aspx). 040904e4 is equivalent to 0409=US and 04e4=multilingual charset (decimal 1252)

Comment: This Code has an error. `VerQueryValue` returns the length of the string **including** the terminating zero. `SetString` appends the terminating zero to the string. This leads to unexpected behaviour. If you append sth. to say `strProductName` it looks like nothing happened, because there now is a zero in the middle of the string. Functions that take a zero-terminated string will take only the part of the original product name. It should be either: `strProductName.SetString((LPCSTR)pvProductName, iProductNameLen -1 );` or `strProductName.SetString((LPCSTR)pvProductName);`.

Comment: @Holger that's not at all obvious from reading the documentation, and the code is no longer available to me for testing. I wouldn't presume to make that correction without testing.

Comment: @Mark: There you are perfectly right. It's not very well documented. I was trying to find, why my string concatenation did not work. It was at a completely different place in the code. Finally I traced it down to the `VerQueryValue` function. There it dawned to me that there might be an additional zero in the string data. Trimmed that off and voila it worked. Maybe you just put a hint in your solution to ask people to look at my comment. If you just use the string by itself you would not notice the difference. As soon as you `+=` another string or use the `+` operator the symptom shows.

Comment: works under WinCE (Windows Compact Embedded) 2013 perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: When I tried it, I am able to get only the first character. I tried debugging using Visual studio.

Comment: If using TCHAR (wchar) instead of single-byte characters, use `std::vector<TCHAR> data(dwSize);` instead of `std::vector<BYTE> data(dwSize);` and `LPCTSTR` instead of `LPCSTR`.

Comment: @AlainD the return value from `GetFileVersionInfoSize` is in bytes, so the vector should be bytes as well or it will be the wrong size. You might be right about needing better casting to pull out the results though.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Ah yes, possibly `...data(dwSize / sizeof(TCHAR))` to be absolutely correct. Most of the returned data is blank so I hadn't spot that bug. Good spot. Using `TCHAR` and casting to `LPCTSTR` worked for me with VS2019 using C++14. My project `Character Set` is set (by default) to `Use Unicode Character Set`.

Answer (score 17):

To get a language independent result to Mark's answer change :

```
   // replace "040904e4" with the language ID of your resources
    !VerQueryValue(&data[0], _T("\\StringFileInfo\\040904e4\\ProductVersion"), &pvProductVersion, &iProductVersionLen))
{
    TRACE("Can't obtain ProductName and ProductVersion from resources\n");
    return false;
}
```

To

```
UINT                uiVerLen = 0;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO*   pFixedInfo = 0;     // pointer to fixed file info structure
// get the fixed file info (language-independent) 
if(VerQueryValue(&data[0], TEXT("\\"), (void**)&pFixedInfo, (UINT *)&uiVerLen) == 0)
{
    return false;
}

 strProductVersion.Format("%u.%u.%u.%u", 
    HIWORD (pFixedInfo->dwProductVersionMS),
    LOWORD (pFixedInfo->dwProductVersionMS),
    HIWORD (pFixedInfo->dwProductVersionLS),
    LOWORD (pFixedInfo->dwProductVersionLS));
```

Comment: This gets different information from Mark Ransom's answer. The values you retrieve are four integers from the PRODUCTVERSION top-level line in the resource file; however Marks' answer retrieves the string "ProductVersion" from under the "StringFileInfo" block.

Answer (score 7):

Something like might get you started, perhaps:

```
TCHAR moduleName[MAX_PATH+1];
(void)GetModuleFileName(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), moduleName, MAX_PATH);
DWORD dummyZero;
DWORD versionSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(moduleName, &dummyZero);
if(versionSize == 0)
{
    return NULL;
}
void* pVersion = malloc(versionSize);
if(pVersion == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
if(!GetFileVersionInfo(moduleName, NULL, versionSize, pVersion))
{
    free(pVersion);
    return NULL;
}

UINT length;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO* pFixInfo;
VERIFY(VerQueryValue(pVersionInfo, const_cast<LPTSTR>("\\"), (LPVOID*)&pFixInfo, &length));
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this will give you raw access to the resource data and get you started:

```
HRSRC res = ::FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_VERSION_ID), RT_VERSION);
DWORD size = ::SizeofResource(NULL, res);
HGLOBAL mem = ::LoadResource(NULL, res);
LPVOID raw_data = ::LockResource(mem);
...
::FreeResource(mem);
```

Answer (score 6):

Beware!
Using FindResource..LockResource is not correct. It will sometimes work (as it did in my small demo program) and sometimes cause access violations (example: the production code I was making the demo for).

The VerQueryValue() documentation states that you should call GetFileVersionInfoSize and  GetFileVersionInfo instead.
Raymond Chen explains, see http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/26/1365215.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a bit more googleing found the [following](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/files/fileinformation/article.php/c4481) on CodeGuru.  Basically this approach uses the **CFileVersionInfo** object to get on any given file.  It should be interesting to see if it works on the currently running .EXE file and on Windows CE.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I receive Access Violation when use `VerQueryValueA`. But I never got this error when use `VerQueryValueW`. I think something wrong with `VerQueryValueA` in version.dll. Therefore I use `VerQueryValueW` instead of `VerQueryValueA` even in projects Multi-byte Character Encoding. [Here is my code of `ReadVersion` function](http://blog.coolsoftware.ru/2012/08/verqueryvalue-access-violation.html)