# Get the version number of VS C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read from a version resource in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316626/how-do-i-read-from-a-version-resource-in-visual-c)

I add a ressource "version" to my C++ Visual Studio project and now I want to read
back this value in my code!

How is this possible?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You access the resource with the function [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and access it with the function [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). At the second like you will also get a complete example to access and update the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it in [Project: Merge](http://www.projectmerge.com):

```
std::wstring ReadProcessVersion( const std::wstring& filename )
{
    char        buffer[ 8192 ];
    wchar_t*    version;
    UINT        size;

    if( GetFileVersionInfo( filename.c_str(), NULL, sizeof( buffer ), buffer ))
    {
        if( VerQueryValue( buffer, L"\\StringFileInfo\\080904B0\\FileVersion", reinterpret_cast< void** >( &version ), &size ))
        {
            return version;
        }
    }
    return L"";
}
```

If I remember rightly, the resource identifier `080904B0` is locale dependent.  (I only ever have English.)